# Error "The user denied your request" when generate Access Token Instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

When attempting to generate the instagram access token, the following error is returned

[image]

**My Instagram settings**

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Autorization App]

Comment: It looks like it's only happening with some accounts though. Have you tried requesting access for a different IG account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this question: [https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize api login error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449162/https-api-instagram-com-oauth-authorize-api-login-error)

Have you tried switching your browser language to English and retrying the connection?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in language. Add parameter **&hl=en** to the link of authorization - it's solving the issue.

[https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize api login error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449162/https-api-instagram-com-oauth-authorize-api-login-error)

Comment: Man, you saved my day. 
Although the authorization page was already in english, it didn't work until I added `&hl=en` to the adress. Привет русскоязычным!