# https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize api login error

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Instagram login API is in use.
After approving the app, the following error occurs.

The user denied your request.

It worked well until yesterday.
What's the problem?

Comment: Is this happening for multiple accounts? Are you able to log in to the IG website normally?

Comment: When I try to log in, I get an "abnormal login attempt detected". 

After entering code, login normally.

Only a few users of our site can not log in.

Comment: So after entering login code, and logging in on the normal IG website, are you still getting this error on your app?

Comment: Yes.
The IG site is normally logged in.
But my site keeps getting errors.

Comment: Same issue here. It looks like the "Authorize" button has the same action as "Cancel" button on Instagram page when you log in for the first time. It only does affect part of the users..

Comment: Is there no way to solve it?
Users can not log in

Comment: We are facing this issue in an Ionic app. The user is not redirected properly after granting access. Bases on our registration statistics, the problem started on Friday March 29, 2019.

Comment: @jeypark Are you sure it stopped working _today_ (April 1st)?

Comment: Can anyone tell me about some applications (iOS or web) where we can try to replicate this error?

Comment: Same issue here. Old approved app start to receive "user_denied" error on Friday Instagram upadate (around 11am March 29). All my test accounts can authorize, few friends from Europe can authorize, but most of my app users - can't.

Comment: @jeypark could you send me the docs you follow?, I need to integrate its API with my web app but it didn't work

Comment: @AhmedE.Eldeeb What do you mean?
could not understand.

Comment: in my web app, i need to make user able to share connect to instrgram but i didn't find anything for this in instagram docs

Comment: @AhmedE.Eldeeb You can get permission here https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Answer (score 31):

The value of the authorization buttons is different in other languages which probably causes the issue, I guess an issue on Instagram itself.

After doing some research I found out you can change the language of the authorization screen using the following parameter:

`&hl=en`

Did some test with my apps and it's solving the issue.

Note: The language parameter is not in the official documentation, so in theory they could change it, but for now it is fixing the issue.

Comment: Works for me as well! Thank you very much:)

Comment: Do you have a web based application or is it on iOS? @Koen

Comment: @ViktorJarnheimer web based application

Comment: It took me a while to figure out where to insert this parameter in omniauth in Rails, so for those that are in the same boat as I am, you can use the `authorize_params` in `omniauth.rb` like so: `provider :instagram, ENV['INSTAGRAM_KEY'], ENV['INSTAGRAM_SECRET'], authorize_params: { hl: "en" }`

Comment: Awesome this works thanks. For people who have users in different countries this will be somewhat challenging for them to understand the authorize screen though.

Comment: how can be add The language parameter in node ?@PascalLindelauf

Answer (score 10):

*Workaround*

I can confirm that there is a problem in other languages except English.

I had the same problem. If you set the web main language to English, you will be logged in.

Comment: 감사합니다  ㅎㅎ 
한국분이시네요 ㅎㅎㅎ

Comment: How did you resolve it? I can't add a language parameter to the oauth call.

Comment: @SativaNL you need to change the language on your browser / pc

Answer (score 7):

I have same error, but `&hl=en` helps me.
Facebook and instagram support completely not competent, there are huge problems and no way to inform support about them.

Comment: can you explain where you add these parameters?

Comment: in the end of your url:
Ex: `...&response_type=code&scope=basic&hl=en`

Comment: but how to pass from req.body data

Answer (score 2):

I came here after I figured the actual problem out. The problem is the value of the confirm button. Apparently they have some code that checks it for being equal to "Authorize". You can see how that might form an issue in other languages.

https://twitter.com/vdwijngaert/status/1112999130878619649

Answer (score 0):

*Temporary workaround*

I got the same problem today.
The app/client was revoked without a reason and any time that I tried to re-auth (get the auth/Access token) I received an error message with:

```
error_reason=user_denied
error=access_denied
error_description=The+user+denied+your+request
```

-

I solved by changing the browser language during the auth-code procedure (your own or via third party websites like pixelunion).
I used Firefox with the addon Language Switch
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/languageswitch/
and **Set the language to "English"** (the plugin adds a flag in the toolbar. Left click on it and then on the "English" text).
After changing to the (accepted) English language the procedure finished without issues.

---

Note: it's almost impossible to contact the instagram/facebook support. Really disappointing.

Comment: It's obvious that a "FIX" is only possible from Instagram/fb.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the latest version of Google Chrome.

I had the same issue but updating Chrome fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. In my case it is the iPhone App. I use "UIWebView" to display the login screen of Inatagram.
In the case of English, it works well, and in the case of Japanese, it becomes an error.