# Instagram API stopped authorizing

Tags: instagram-api

I'm having new issues with Instagram users authorizing my app. After the user presses authorize it doesn't do anything. Has there been any new changes? I can't seem to duplicate the issue on my own but I'm getting a ton of messages from my users.

Comment: You haven't added nearly enough information for the community to accurately assess what's going on. Please use an appropriate technology/language tag and provide some sample code that's illustrates what exactly is not working (see [Minimum, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) & crash logs (if any).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an Instagram customer service question and not a programming question. We can't troubleshoot issues with your specific account because we have no access to your account. Contact Instagram via their site. For more information, see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/62576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the issue here -
 [https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize api login error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449162/https-api-instagram-com-oauth-authorize-api-login-error/55450156?fbclid=IwAR0hIB06_1V_QNk3_gN_5QQ3-7Di5OEr7HM9dYQlOOuiv3DtMupFfxEsta8)

It seems to be an unaddressed Instagram bug